# How to access Pair<> of Java in JNI?

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface, std-pair, jnienv

I have `ArrayList<Pair<Pair<Float, Float>, Pair<Float, Float>>>` on Java side and want to use this data in JNI.

What methods and classes to use to convert to `std::pair<std::pair<float, float>, std::pair<float, float>>`

I tried following

`jclass pairClass = env->FindClass("android/util/Pair");`

`jfieldID pairGetKey = env->GetFieldID(pairClass, "first", "java/util/Objects");`

`pairGetKey` is always null

Comment: `ArrayList<Pair<Pair<Float, Float>, Pair<Float, Float>>>`... Why?

Comment: JNI is a `C` interface. Good luck.

Comment: @RichardCritten is there a way to access Fields of Pair. 
I was able to access ArrayList data by :

```jclass arrayListClass = env->FindClass("java/util/ArrayList");

    jmethodID arrayListSize = env->GetMethodID(arrayListClass, "size", "()I");```

Comment: Call the the Pair methods `getKey()` and `getValue()`  from JNI.  Basically yes you are going to have to bind to every Java class in your structure from JNI; get the values and recreate it in `C++` element by element.

Comment: @RichardCritten android.util.Pair do not have those methods. Instead it has first and second field as public.

Comment: Surely it's `java/lang/Object`, not `java/util/Objects`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type of the field has to be given as a *signature*; that is, you need to use the `int` -> `I`, `T[]` -> `[T`, `reference.Type` -> `Lreference/Type;` encoding. Also, the type of the field is `java.lang.Object`, not `java.util.Objects`.

```
jfieldID first = env->GetFieldID(pairClass, "first", "Ljava/lang/Object;");
jfieldID second = env->GetFieldID(pairClass, "second", "Ljava/lang/Object;");
```

The rest is tedious, but not hard:

```
jfloat extract_float(JNIEnv *env, jobject f) {
    // Note the syntax of signatures: float floatValue() has signature "()F"
    return env->CallFloatMethod(f,
        env->GetMethodID(env->FindClass("java/lang/Float"), "floatValue", "()F"));
}
std::pair<jobject, jobject> extract_pair(JNIEnv *env, jobject p) {
    jclass pairClass = env->FindClass("android/util/Pair");
    jfieldID first = env->GetFieldID(pairClass, "first", "Ljava/lang/Object;");
    jfieldID second = env->GetFieldID(pairClass, "second", "Ljava/lang/Object;");

    return std::pair(env->GetObjectField(p, first), env->GetObjectField(p, second));
}

JNIEnv *env;
jobject pair;
auto [f1, f2] = extract_pair(env, pair);
auto [f11, f12] = extract_pair(env, f1);
auto [f21, f22] = extract_pair(env, f2);
std::pair p(
        std::pair(extract_float(env, f11), extract_float(env, f12)),
        std::pair(extract_float(env, f21), extract_float(env, f22)));
```

Though, I think I must ask, do you actually need to do this? Can you preprocess the nested pairs to something nicer on the Java side? Doing it on this side is ugly.

Comment: Nitpick: getting three references per invocation of `extract_pair` will quickly exhaust the local reference table.

Comment: @Botje I'm not familiar with the JNI. Would it be safe/idiomatic to use a `static` variable in `extract_pair`/`extract_float` to hold the offending variables?

Comment: No, the references expire once you return to Java. But that can be solved by rewriting `extract_pair` as a lambda with captures. Not that you rewrite your answer — just mentioning it for future readers.

Comment: When I update Pair to android x's implementation I get a crash in my proguarded release build. I tried adding Pair to the pro guards rules but was unsuccessful in getting it to recognize the fields "first" and "second". Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat i have the same issue on release mode

Comment: I honestly can't recall but here's all my PAIR stuff.
Proguard:
-keep public class androidx.core.util.Pair {
    *;
}

field ID:
"Landroidx/core/util/Pair;"

fetching the object in the pair:
env->GetFieldID(java_class, "first", "Ljava/lang/Object;");

If you are doing all that then it's the standard rebuild, etc...

Comment: No problem! I hope it helped!